# Eval, parse, function arguments, and environments

Tags: r

I have a function that takes as an argument a logical statement.  For example,

```
cpdist(fitted.model, evidence = (A == "a") & (B == "b"))
```

I want this function to work with various "evidence" arguments, so I wrote

```
ev <- paste("(", evidence.variables, "=='",  sapply(evidence.values, as.character), ")",
                  sep = "", collapse = " & ")
cpdist(fitted.model, evidence = eval(parse(text = ev)))
```

This works when I call it from global environment or from within a for loop.  However, I want to wrap this code in a larger function (which itself is called from within a loop).  When I do that, I get the error: "Error in parse(text = ev) : object 'ev' not found".

eval() has "envir" and "enclos" arguments.  I have tried setting those arguments to different environments, but it hasn't worked.  Environments are still a hazy subject to me.  Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: A suggestion.... don't use `eval(parse(...` see `library(fortunes);fortune(181)`. As for this specific question. Is `cpdist` your function? Where is the reproducible example?

Comment: A further suggestion. If ou are using a funciton that is not in one of the packages loaded by default then NAME THE PACKAGE.

Comment: For an example of how to do this sort of thing "correctly" see the code in `subset.data.frame`, in particular the handling of the `subset` argument.