# Eval and environments in R: Why can't Eval() find a variable defined in the environment where it evaluates the expression

Tags: r

I have a question concerning environments in evaluating expressions.  Specifically, I have a function bnlearn::cpdist that takes a logical expression as an argument.  I wish to use a variable to specify that argument, so I wish to use eval(parse(text = string)).  But in the case this is happening within the environment of a larger function, the eval function can't find the variable "string", despite it having been defined in that environment.  I am confused.  Here is the code the reproduces the problem.

```
# The function is from the bnlearn package, which handles Bayesian networks
library(bnlearn)
#Example data
data(learning.test)
#Fitting a model
fitted = bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test)
#The function in question generates samples from the PDF of one node given the values of others.  
posterior = cpdist(fitted, "D", (A == "a" & C == "b")) #Notice the awkward logical statement arg
prop.table(table(posterior))

#I want to use character variables instead of the logical statement.
#If I use parse and eval to specify the logical statement I have no issues.
evidence.nodes <- c("A", "C")
evidence.values <- c("a", "b")
ev <- paste("(", evidence.nodes, "=='",
                  sapply(evidence.values, as.character), "')",
                  sep = "", collapse = " & ")
posterior <- cpdist(fitted, "D", eval(parse(text = ev)))


#But what I want to do is apply do this from within a function
getPosterior <- function(fitted, target, ev.nodes, ev.values){
    ev <- paste("(", ev.nodes, "=='",
                  sapply(ev.values, as.character), "')",
                  sep = "", collapse = " & ")

     posterior <- cpdist(fitted, "D", eval(parse(text = ev)))
     prop.table(table(posterior))
}

#Here is where the problem lies.  The following works if "ev" is already defined as it was above.  However, if you remove ev from the global environment, then it fails.  I do not understand why it cannot find the ev object defined within the function's environment.

new.data <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), C = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))    
rm(ev)
for(i in 1:nrow(new.data)){
    print(getPosterior(fitted, "D", names(new.data), new.data[i, ]))    
}
```

Comment: There are lots of issues here, but first off, the error is coming from `parse()` not `eval()`. If you fix that then you get another error, this time from `eval()`. Where or in what object do you want the expression `ev` (from `getPosterior()`) to be evaluated? I.e. where should it find `A` etc.

Comment: You ask a simple question about variable scope in eval() but you provide overly complicated and irrelevant code ... (-1, sorry)

Comment: I voted to close your [earlier version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20183230/324364) of this question, since this one is actually an improvement (IMHO).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I gave the code because it seems people want to be able to reproduce the error.  What I don't get is that the code works eval() can find the "ev" object when its defined in the global environment but not when it is defined within the function.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue like this. I solved it with super assignation on the variable that was not found in my function.

```
var <<- 5
```